# Show that subspace is maximal ideal in commutative Banach algebra

Tags: functional-analysis, analysis, operator-theory, spectral-theory

> Show that the subspace $c_{0} = \{ x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots ) \in \ell^{\infty} : \lim x_n = 0 \}$ is a maximal ideal in $c = \{ x = (x_{1}, x_{2}, \ldots ) \in \ell^{\infty} : \lim x_n \text{ exists } \}$ by finding a linear multiplicative functional with $c_{0}$ as its kernel.

I already showed that $c_{0}$ is a proper, closed ideal. I am stuck on showing that it is a maximal ideal by finding a multiplicative linear functional $\phi$ with $\ker(\phi) = c_{0}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider $\phi(x_1,x_2,\dots):=\lim_n x_n$.
It's clearly linear and maps to the scalar field, its kernel is just $c_0$, and thus it's a one codimensional subspace, hence must be maximal.

Comment: Thanks. It seems clear enough. I was wonderig as a follow up question: Is $c_{0}$ a maximal ideal in $\ell^{\infty}$?

Comment: I would say no since we have the ideal $c$ in between $c_{0}$ and $\ell^{\infty}$.

Comment: @huikan, $c$ is not an ideal.

Comment: @Ruy Is it because $c$ is not necessarily closed by mutliplication of elements in $\ell^{\infty}$, i.e. some (bounded) sequence might not converge and multiplying with a convergent sequence might not converge?

Comment: But then again, is $c_0$ maximal in $\ell^{\infty}$?